# How to add custom select options in a custom admin form

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, admin, adminform, custom-admin-grid

I am creating a custom fom in admin and want to load the custom select option in the form as a select field options.

Below is my code :

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Grid/Edit/Form.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Edit;
 
 
/**
 * Adminhtml Add New Row Form.
 */
class Form extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store
     */
    protected $_systemStore;
 
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry             $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory     $formFactory
     * @param array                                   $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config $wysiwygConfig,
        \Vendor\Module\Model\Status $options,
        array $data = []
    ) 
    {
        $this->_options = $options;
        $this->_wysiwygConfig = $wysiwygConfig;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }
 
    /**
     * Prepare form.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        
        $dateFormat = $this->_localeDate->getDateFormat(\IntlDateFormatter::SHORT);
        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('row_data');
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
            ['data' => [
                            'id' => 'edit_form', 
                            'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', 
                            'action' => $this->getData('action'), 
                            'method' => 'post'
                        ]
            ]
        );
 
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('question_');
        
        $fieldset->addField(
            'name',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'name',
                'label' => __('NAME'),
                'id' => 'name',
                'title' => __('NAME'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
            ]
        );

            $fieldset->addField(
                'email',
                'text',
                [
                    'name' => 'email',
                    'label' => __('Email'),
                    'id' => 'email',
                    'title' => __('Email'),
                    'class' => 'required-entry',
                    'required' => true,
                ]
            );
        

        $fieldset->addField('is_answered', 'select', 
           [
              'name' => 'is_answered',
              'label' => __('Status'),
              'options' => ['1' => __('Pending By Seller'), '0' => __('Pending By Admin')],
              'required' => true,
           ]);

        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);
 
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

I want to load custom data(email) entries from custom table in the email field as a drop-down in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below code

Create source provider for email values

> Vendor\Module\Model\Email\Options.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Email;

class Options implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{ 
    /**
     * Return array of options as value-label pairs, eg. value => label
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        // You can write your code to fetch email values from custom table and convert it to as value => label pair
        return [
            'value' => 'Label',
            'demo@mail.com' => 'demo@mail.com',
            'demo1@mail.com' => 'demo@mail.com',
        ];
    }
}
```

> Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Edit\Form.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Edit;

/**
 * Adminhtml Add New Row Form.
 */
class Form extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store
     */
    protected $_systemStore;

    /**
     * @var \Vendor\Module\Model\Email\Options
     */
    protected $_emailOptions;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry             $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory     $formFactory
     * @param array                                   $data
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context, \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry, \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory, \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config $wysiwygConfig, \Vendor\Module\Model\Status $options, \Vendor\Module\Model\Email\Options $emailOptions, array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_options = $options;
        $this->_wysiwygConfig = $wysiwygConfig;
        $this->_emailOptions = $emailOptions;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare form.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {

        $dateFormat = $this
            ->_localeDate
            ->getDateFormat(\IntlDateFormatter::SHORT);
        $model = $this
            ->_coreRegistry
            ->registry('row_data');
        $form = $this
            ->_formFactory
            ->create(['data' => ['id' => 'edit_form', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', 'action' => $this->getData('action') , 'method' => 'post']]);

        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('question_');

        $fieldset->addField(
            'name',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'name',
                'label' => __('NAME'),
                'id' => 'name',
                'title' => __('NAME'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
            ]
        );

        $fieldset->addField(
            'email',
            'select',
            [
                'name' => 'email',
                'label' => __('Email'),
                'id' => 'email',
                'title' => __('Email'),
                'values' => $this->_emailOptions->toOptionArray() 'class' => 'select', 'required' => true, ]);

        $fieldset->addField('is_answered', 'select', 
        [
          'name' => 'is_answered',
          'label' => __('Status'),
          'options' => ['1' => __('Pending By Seller'), '0' => __('Pending By Admin')],
          'required' => true,
        ]);

        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add select field like this :

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'custom_dropdown',
    'select',
    [
        'name' => 'custom_dropdown',
        'label' => __('Custom Dropdown'),
        'title' => __('Custom Dropdown'),
        'values' => [0 => __('No'), 1 => __('Yes')],
        'class' => 'select'
    ]
);
```

Replace `custom_dropdown` value by your field name & add your custom data array in `values` field.

Comment: This will work if we have only a few options but in my case there are number entries in that custom table. it won't be possible to write them all here in this file.
I have tried this but by doing this the values of these option comes as 1,2,3,4... etc. and i want them to be same as select options.

Comment: You can add like this : $this->attributeSetOptions->toOptionArray(); Here toOptionArray() with return custom data.

Comment: I am a bit confused can you explain it. how actually i can do this.

Comment: vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/AttributeSet/Form.php here you can see that how dynamic value set as I told you. Let me know still if you have confusion.